# Using a twig extension to mark link as active?

Tags: symfony, templates, service, routes

I want to efficiently find the active page on my navbar to apply a different class to it.

Currently, I do it this way :

```
{% if app.request.get('_route') == 'route_name' %}
    <li class="active">
{% else %}
    <li>
{% endif %}
<a href="{{ path('route_name') }}">Link</a></li>
```

Is there a way to do it without repeating myself so much ?

I was thinking of using a twig extension to check a given route, but I didn't find a way to get the request route in the extension code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partials are how you can avoid repetition with Twig. Create a `_link.html.twig` file like this:

```
{% if app.request.get('_route') == 'route_name' %}
    <li class="active">
{% else %}
    <li>
{% endif %}
<a href="{{ path('route_name') }}">Link</a></li>
```

And in your template do:

```
{% for route in routeToBeLinked %}
    {% include '_link.html.twig' with { 'route_name': route } %}
{% endfor %}
```

Documentation about include: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

Comment: Why is that ? It seems to work as expected like this. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that line of code... I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think good idea will be apply "macro"

There is little bit another case, but I do such way for my filter tab:

```
 <ul>
        {{ _self.filter('unpaid', 'unpaid') }}
        {{ _self.filter('unproduced', 'not yet in production') }}
        {{ _self.filter('arrived', 'delivery will receive') }}
 </ul>

{% macro filter(key, name) %}
    <li class="{{ _filter == key ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{ path('__order', {'_filter': key}) }}">{{ name }}</a></li>
{% endmacro %}
```

_filter is variable assigned at controller

So you can organize your case similar way